# C# how do I get the first element of a dictionary and move to another

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that has 2 dictionaries
Queue and Playing

And I want to grab the first element from Queue and move to Playing when Playing is empty
The only code piece I have is
 `if(Playing.Count == 0){}`
Any way I can do that?

PS: Both Playing and queue require an int and a player, the player is defined, the int is the player ID

**EDIT**

Code example:

```
public static Dictionary<int, player> queue = new Dictionary<int, player>();
public static Dictionary<int, player> Playing = new Dictionary<int, 
player>();

if (Regex.IsMatch(m.GetString(1).Substring(0, 1), @"\.|\!|\?|\-|\+"))
{
    var cmdprefix = m.GetString(1).Substring(0, 1); //Set the command prefix
    var words = m.GetString(1).ToLower().Split(' '); //Split the spacebar into words.

    if (words[0].StartsWith(cmdprefix + "queue")); //If words starts with the prefix and "queue"
    {
        queue.Add(m.GetInt(0), new player()
        {
            username = m.GetString(1), //Nickname of player
        });
    }

    if(Playing.Count == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: how to insert element to dictionary, how to remove element from dictionary, try to google it, its a lot of easier than ask your own question, there are quantum answers for this topic on the internet even on stackoverflow... read: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It doesn't fit very well, I am trying to get the first and move it, not removing
Plus the player ID is something that is not in order when it joins a dictionary

Comment: There is no first in Dictionary.  Look at Queue.   That is some strange formatting.

Comment: @Sport Dictionary doesn't guarantee the order of elements. So there is no *first* element.  You can not use it like a queue/list/array

Answer (score -1):

I believe I have answered your question with below code. The trick is that an [item is removed from a Dictionary by its key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if(Playing.Count == 0)
{
    Playing.Add(
        m.GetInt(0), 
        new player{ username = m.GetString(1)
    }
    queue.Remove(m.GetInt(0);
}
```

Also note the comments from @paparazzo and @Eser that [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is the wrong choice. [`Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx), [`SortedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) should be better.

Comment: For next time you ask a question; try not to disturb the very code regarding the question with `m`, various `GetString` and Regex. The clearer you write your question, the faster and better answer you will get. Spending half an hour writing the question is not to be frowned upon. Also, if you spend a lot of time of writing the question you might solve the problem yourself and learn about programming problem solving at the same time. Happy hacking!

Comment: M is a message, I need to get from queue

Comment: @Sport In all friendlyness, you are missing my point. Whatever `m` is, it doesn't bring any value to the question; instead it convolutes your question and makes it harder to read. Which will lead to downvoting and fewer answers. HTH.